# IF EXISTS and update/delete in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I'm currently writing a stored procedure to update an entire table or on attribute level.

I look if its supposed to update entire table or not. If yes then update entire, if not then look on attribute level whether it's supposed to be a new row, update row, or delete row.

To my help I have three tables: one that says if whole table is to be updated, a new/update table, and a delete table. They consist of data telling what table has changed and when the change occured as well a GUID.

Any ideas on how to write this? Preferred would also be dynamic code but that is not a must. For instance something like:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * from DB1.Schema1.Table1 where UpdateAll = 1) --update all rows, all attributes
   BEGIN
    'truncate/drop table? update whole table from another table from DB2?'
   END

IF EXISTS (SELECT * from DB1.Schema1.Table1 where UpdateAll = 0) --Only on attribute level
  BEGIN
   'Update table in DB1 based on Delete, or new/update table. And this step 
    is on attribute level (not update all attributes as step above)'
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to explore the MERGE statement in SQL server: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

If it doesn't full fill your requirement then go with dynamic query    execution using sp_executesql: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I think dynamic quering is the goal here. But Im having trouble seeing how I should progress so maybe its better to write normal query first. Otherwise You think I have the right idea? Thanks for the reply =)